# Export database through mysqldump, or Magento admin?

Tags: import, mysql, sql, export, backup

I was looking at this doc:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/restoring_a_backup_of_a_magento_database

which says to add a few lines to your dump file or the lines will be included from a database export through the admin.

I just ran one version through the admin, and one version as a mysqldump file, and both of them contain the lines:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Is this the correct, expected output? I haven't had any issues importing the database, but want to make sure the auto increments will increase normally (for invoice ids specifically)

Answer (score 2):

I would never use the Magento Admin to export purely due to the fact that Magento itself was not written to facilitate highly efficient export with minimal locking or interruption to the store. I only recommend it in the case that you have no SSH / shell access to your store and are recovering. This is the only case in which I've used it.

As an aside there is an issue of filesystem sessions that lock you from using the admin panel while long-running operations are in progress - I would be wary of starting a large export as you may not be able to use the store again in the same admin session until the export completes.

Comment: Hence the use of Firefox and Chrome simultaneously for admin at times. One browser, one session.

Comment: Or... you could just open an incognito window ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the output does seem to be correct.

As for your main question about database export, I'll definitely recommend dumping the MySQL through SSH over Magento Admin any day due to a few reasons:-

- Magento's internal database export tool is not very efficient.
- You may not have a high enough timeout limit in which case the export may timed out even before it is completed.
- If you are on shared hosting, exporting the database will contribute to increased resource usage of your hosting account. Most shared hosting provider will not calculate the the resource consumed by database export if it is done through SSH or your hosting control panel.

For those who do not have SSH access, they should still be able to export their database through their hosting control panel like cPanel if they have one.