# How to copy store configuration to a new magento install?

Tags: database, configuration, data-replication

I have implemented a new magento install  (with its own database) in order to have a development version of my e-commerce site.

I would like now to copy the configuration / products ... (everything in fact) of the original version to have an exact copy of my shop.

how can I do that?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export database through mysqldump, or Magento admin?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32667/export-database-through-mysqldump-or-magento-admin)

Answer (score 2):

Just take a backup of your current store and import this database onto your staging site.

Depending in your skill level you can dump and import using
- Command line using mysqldump
- Phpmyadmin
- sql work bench (heidi sql for example)